# How to redirect requests from domain.com to www.domain in Wai/Warp app?

Tags: haskell, redirect, haskell-warp, servant

My site is built in Haskell/Servant and Wai/Warp. I need to redirect all requests from my `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` with the the 301 or 302 status.  I know I can do that with the help of Wai/Warp somehow. How exactly?

```
startApp :: IO ()
startApp = run 1234 app
```

Answer (score 1):

The package [`wai-util`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-util-0.8) has a convenience function [`redirect'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-util-0.8/docs/Network-Wai-Util.html#v:redirect-39-) to create such a `Response`, so you should be able to do something like

```
app :: Application
app req respond = respond =<< redirect' status302 [] uri
  where
    Just uri = parseURI "http://example.com/"
```

Comment: You can look at `req` and decide however you want if and where you want to redirect.

Comment: since on localhost I don't have "www" in a request, on localhost I can't debug it, can it? I need it because I don't know exactly what's inside a request and how "www" is represented.